# javascript percentage rounding

Tags: javascript

I have a value of `0.9019497053624151`. It needs to display `90`, so it is ideal to use the ff formula? by the way this is a percentage

```js
console.log(Math.round(0.9019497053624151 * 10) / 10 * 100);
```

I tried rounding it off to 1 decimal place and then * 100, should I round it to 1 or 2 decimal places?

What do you call this percentage rounding? That from a value of `0.9019497053624151%` the expected result is `90%`

Comment: is using tofixed an ideal solution like 0.9019497053624151.toFixed(2) * 100
?

Comment: This is just rounding to the nearest hundredth and multiplying the result by 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `toFixed` method ([see documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed))

You can specify the number of decimal you want. Example :

```js
console.log(0.9119497053624151.toFixed(2));
console.log(0.9119497053624151.toFixed(4));
console.log(0.9119497053624151.toFixed(1));
console.log(0.9.toFixed(2));
```

You can then easely multiply it by 100 as you want :)

`myNumber.toFixed(2) * 100`

Comment: Be careful. Integer values like 0 or 1 will throw an error with toFixed(). Ex. 1.toFixed(2) // Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

Your question is 100% clear, but you should round it to 2 decimal places if you want only whole percents.
Also because you are using the round function, just multiply it by 100 (i.e. convert to percentage) and let it round to the nearest whole if that is what you are trying to accomplish.

```js
console.log(Math.round(0.9019497053624151 * 100));
```

Comment: Thanks. It's helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write precentage of random number or something like that?

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 %
```

Math.random creates a float like [0,1[

Math.floor returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.